# MATLAB Code: Help required on algorithm

Tags: matlab

I have the following code from my predecessor. I am unable to figure out what is the math that is happening here and how is the values avgCov and stdCov are different, and what they signify. 
Cprofile_f is a curve similar to gaussian curve, like a peak. Cprofile_f is an array of known size (5700).
b1, d1 are index values. Usually, b1 is 2000, d1 is 4300.

```
         avgCov=sum(Cprofile_f(b1:d1))/(d1-b1)
         stdCov=0;
         for ii=b1:d1
             stdCov =stdCov + sqrt((avgCov - Cprofile_f(ii))^2);
         end 

         stdCov =1- stdCov/(d1-b1)/avgCov
```

Trying to figure out, what stdCov mean here.

Comment: `avgCov` is the sum of a vector created from `Cprofile_f` divided by a scalar.  Are you sure you don't want to use elementwise division and sum each quotient (if this is what you want to do, I'd probably do it an alternative way)?  `stdCov` is an incremented value that is the square root of the difference of `avgCov` and each value from `Cprofile_f` in `avgCov` and squared, and then one minus the whole thing.  This looks like statistics to me.  Is that what you want?  I'm just trying to see if I understand before answering.

Comment: Yes, it is statistics, which I have no idea about the physical significance.

Comment: The answer below may be what you're looking for then.  Do you have a programming question or just a math question?  Your predecessor really should have commented his code.

Comment: Math question and what would one get from doing this way

Comment: `avgCov` is the average of the 2000th through 4300th elements of `Cprofile_f`.  `stdCov` in line 2 initializes the variable, in line 4 it increments what I believe is the standard deviation, and in line 7 calculates, as the other user said, the coefficient of variation (standard deviation / mean).  They are taking it away from one probably because it's the most efficient way to write the code and still have the math be correct, but you'd have to work out the math to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's computing the average (avgCov) and standard deviation (stdCov, sort of) in order to compute 1 minus the coefficient of variation (stored in stdCov).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation